# Enqueing stylesheets produces dubble css filenames

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

when im trying to enque my child themes stylesheet in the child themes functions.php it renders an 404 error in the console due to a dubblename.
Here is the the error and enqueue-script:

```
VM281:165 GET https://tusenochenknopp.se/wp-content/themes/storefront-child-theme/style.cssstyle.css?ver=5.6 net::ERR_ABORTED 404

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'toek_theme_name_scripts' );
function toek_theme_name_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() .'/style.css' );
}
```

Iv'e tried to change the name on the file and in the script, but then i get this error:

```
VM2131:165 GET https://tusenochenknopp.se/wp-content/themes/storefront-child-theme/style.css/child-style.css?ver=5.6 net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Im greatfull for any suggestions on a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the [`get_stylesheet_uri()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_uri/) instead of the [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/)

The former gets the actual URI to the stylesheet file, the latter gets the directory to it. So you'll need to update your code to either of the following:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
```

or

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style.css' );
```

I would recommend the latter because it's more semantic when adding multiple stylesheets later, but either one should ultimately work. Also note that the first one using `get_stylesheet_uri()` only works if your stylesheet is [appropriately named `style.css`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/release/required-theme-files/)

#### Documentation & Function Reference:

| Function | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `get_stylesheet_uri()` | [Retrieves stylesheet URI for current theme.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_uri/) |
| `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` | [Retrieves stylesheet ***directory*** URI for current theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) |
| `wp_enqueue_style()` | [Enqueue (and register) a CSS styleshee](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) |

Comment: Thank you @Xhynk,  it worked. I was wondering about the documentation & function reference under function. You write `get_stylesheet_directory()` but when you click the link it says `get_stylesheet_uri()`. Does the `get_stylesheet_directory()` function exist?

Comment: Ah sorry about that, it was a typo, I fixed that. Yes, `get_stylesheet_directory` exists, but that returns the **path** to the theme instead of the **URI**. When enqueuing assets like that, you'll want to use the `_uri` functions, but when `include`ing, `file_exists()`ing, or checking `filemtime()` etc on files, you'd use the `_directory` functions. `_uri` will output something like `https://example.com/wp-content/themes/theme/style.css`, `_directory` will output something like `/home/users/1234/www/wp-content/themes/theme/style.css`.